# Cinema4d R19's new viewport and Blender's EEVEE

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Cinema4d R19 version has a nice [viewport update.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hG_2dZYMDo)

Is there anything different from Blender's EEVEE?

Or are high-quality viewports now becoming mandatory for DCC software?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Were 3D games have been getting better, we are now seeing these techniques being used in the 3D viewport. So yes they have similarities as they are both using opengl to get close to realistic results in a realtime display. I'm sure that they will use some similar techniques, which will be based on what has been used by game developers.

Comment: @cegaton Exactly my question means that is the development trend of 3D software.
And the C4D viewport and EEVEE seem to be similar to me, but I wondered if there is something different.

Answer (score 1):

**R19** only have preview rendering mode (or advanced OpenGL). Where **Eevee** is a game engine view (close to UE4) Afaik, C4D have no plans on making an actual game engine view. But I could be wrong of course.

Comment: I think you are wrong with EEVEE, BGE is only considered by now to use it. And EEVEE itself is especially not an Game Engine. For now it is just viewport.